# How do I improve a chat application to be less taxing for the server

Tags: javascript, python, chat

A while ago I built a small app using python which allowed users to create small chat rooms. I implemented the server as nothing more than a rest API. The client makes requests and the server gives the appropriate response. The response is recieved by a JavaScript client which keeps on making subsequent requests to the server for updated data. Currently the client sends around 1 request every 3 seconds. I would like my app to be real-time(updates appearing as soon as changes are made), for that to happen I would have to narrow the request interval further to around 0.7 seconds. The problem with this approach is that it is not entirely scalable. Is there any way the server can send data to the client when updates occur?

Comment: Instead of polling, use Comet ( long http connections )

Answer (score 1):

Instead of having the clients pull the server for data, you can have the server push data to the client. The most common protocol to do so (and it is quite close to the standard HTTP protocol) is called WebSockets. WebSockets are an evolving standard, not all browsers support them equally.

Also, in case you use a reverse proxy server at the edge of your network, not all reverse proxy servers support WebSockets, which may also prevent you from using WebSockets.

See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket

Comment: would such a approach work on PaaS like Heroku? as I understand it, websockets are long lived connections to the server.

Comment: I am not sure how stable it will be. Check this: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-labs-websockets